# Optimizing Multilevel MySQL subqueries (folksonomy and taxonomy)

Tags: mysql, subquery, join

I was reading the great [tagging article](http://tagschema.com/blogs/tagschema/2005/10/many-dimensions-of-relatedness-in.html) by Nitin Borwankar and he started me thinking of the ways to implement differnet levels of searches using two tables.

```
tags {
  id,
  tag
}

post_tags {
  id
  user_id
  post_id
  tag_id
}
```

I started with the simple example of `T(U(i))` which means *all tags of all users that have an item i*. I was able to do it with the following SQL:

```
/* get all tags from the users found */
SELECT t.*, vt.* FROM verse_tags as vt
LEFT JOIN tags as t ON t.id = vt.tag_id
WHERE user_id in 
(
    /* Get all user_ids that have taged this item */
    SELECT user_id FROM verse_tags WHERE verse_id = 26046 GROUP BY user_id
)
GROUP BY t.id
```

Then I started with a slightly harder +1 level deep query. `T(U(T(u)))` *which is tags of users using tags like user #*.

```
/* Then get the tags of the user with tags like the user 3 */
SELECT t.id FROM post_tags as pt
LEFT JOIN tags as t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE user_id in 
(
    /* Then get users with these tags */
    SELECT pt.user_id FROM post_tags as pt
    LEFT JOIN tags as t on t.id = pt.tag_id
    WHERE tag_id in
    (
        /* get tags of user */
        SELECT t.id FROM post_tags as pt
        LEFT JOIN tags as t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
        WHERE pt.user_id = 3
        GROUP BY t.id
    )
    GROUP BY user_id
)
GROUP BY t.id
```

However, it since I normally use JOIN's in my queries I am not sure how something like this could be optimized or what design flaws need to be avoided when using subqueries. I have even read that JOIN's should be used instead, but I have no idea how this would be accomplished with the above queries.

How could these queries be optimized?

### UPDATE

1) Replaced `GROUP BY` with `SELECT DISTINCT`. (.74 sec)

2) Replace `WHERE in` with `WHERE exists`. (.40 sec)

3) Added indexes (oops!) (0.09 sec)

4) Back to `WHERE in` (0.08 sec)

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE user_id in
(
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM post_tags WHERE tag_id in
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE user_id = 3
    )
)
```

Running EXPLAIN gives me these results:

```
id  select_type     table       type        possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY         post_tags   index       NULL        tag_id  4   NULL    14  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  post_tags   index_subquery  user_id     user_id 4   func    1   Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  post_tags   index_subquery  user_id,tag_id  tag_id  4   func    1   Using where
```

Comment: It's not clear, why you need `GROUP BY` clause in your subselects: you are not using any aggregate functions nor `HAVING` clause. So they can be simpley replaced with `SELECT distinct` clause, or better put a connection inside a `SELECT clause`: `WHERE exists (SELECT user_id FROM verse_tags vt2 WHERE verse_id = 26046 AND vt.user_id = vt2.user_id)`

Comment: Thanks, the `SELECT DISTINCT` was a good replacement for `GROUP BY`. However, can you expand the second part of your comment into an answer as I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know what "exists" was but when googled it I found a page that explained it. Halved the query time (although there are only a few records so that might mater).

Comment: If you need more tuning, provide also the output of your `EXPLAIN` query (see manual for syntax). Maybe you've missed some index.

Comment: +1 for adding an update.

Answer (score 1):

According to me this is the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`t`.`id`) FROM `post_tags` as `pt`
    left join `tags` as t on `t`.`id` = `pt`.`tag_id`
    where `pt`.`user_id` in(
        SELECT distinct(`pt`.`user_id`) FROM `post_tags` as `pt`
             LEFT JOIN `tags` as `t` on `t`.`id` = `pt`.`tag_id`
              WHERE `pt`.`tag_id` in(
                 SELECT distinct(`tag_id`) FROM `post_tags` 
                 WHERE pt.user_id = 3
            )
    )
```